# How to calculate motor specs for vending machine

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I'm trying to make a vending machine and I need motor to deliver the products. How can I calculate specs such as torque, rpm, power etc? Maximum weight would be 10 soda cans. Let's say each weigh 0.5kg it gives us total of 6kg and there is the spring as well but I don't know how much it weighs. How do I determine which motor to buy? I found one that's 60 rpm, 15 kg/cm torque, 12 V 100mA. Is it any good?

Comment: Torque is not measured in kg/cm - you need to do your homework and enlist the help of a mechanical engineer.

Comment: The website selling the motor measures torque in kg/cm not me.

Comment: That should give you a very big clue about that vendor then.

Comment: It should be kg.cm https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27931/torque-kgcm-what-is-kgcm/98860 The value shown is probably correctly even if the wrong symbol was used by whoever put it on the web. The easiest way to find if this motor will work might be to just buy it and try it. Similarly, you could measure the torque required using eg. a ruler and spring scale.

Comment: Gravity is your friend.  If you build your device right the motor doesn't have to lift 10 soda cans, it just has to stop gravity from dispensing more than one soda can at a time.  If you're clever about this the force can be almost arbitrarily small.

Comment: It's not going to lift it. It's horizontal movement but I thought mass still matters.